# Can windows alone be a cause of damp?

Tags: damp

I recently looked round a house and put in an offer. There is visible damp underneath every window in the house. Would this be solved by replacing the windows? Or is there likely a more serious cause of the damp?

[image]

Comment: That's why you don't buy before having a survey done.

Comment: Yep. All offers should be contingent upon professional inspection, and subject to negotiation to fix any problems the inspection finds.

Comment: Could you provide a better picture?  It's hard to tell what we're looking at with the one you posted.

Answer (score 2):

There could be several reasons:

- Rain coming through an open / improperly closed window
- A leaky roof
- Leaks around the edge of the window, eg cills
- Condensation forming on the inside of the window and running down
- Faulty guttering causing water to run down the outside and come in somehow
- Water crossing the wall barrier - eg bridging across a cavity or soaking through a porous solid wall
- Condensation forming on a cold wall surface, eg an uninsulated wall or one with the vapour barrier in the wrong place (eg a breatheable wall covered in non-breatheable paint)

With any damp problem you need to take a whole-system approach: it may be that there's a series of faults that chain together.  For example a faulty gutter and then an improperly sealed window allowing rain water to come in.

If you don't know what you're doing, professional advice is strongly recommended.  You may have a hypothesis as to why it's happening, but somebody experienced may be able to make a better judgement.

If possible, it's a good idea to inspect on a rainy day, since if it's caused by rain water you may be able to see what the water is doing directly.